# Parallel.Foreach webservice call, searching for the optimal MaxDegreeOfParallelism

Tags: c#, performance, parallel-processing, task-parallel-library, parallel.foreach

We have implemented application wherein we need to process incoming batch. for example a set of Request of certain object type has to be sent to particular webservice to have it processed

We have implemented following snippet to do so. need your help / guidance if there wouldbe any pitfalls on same

```
var options = new ParallelOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 10 };

Parallel.ForEach(request, options, currentRequest =>
{
    ProcessedRequest processedRequest = null;
    try
    {
        currentRequest.DBSave = true;

        processedRequest = CommunicateToService(currentRequest);

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {

        ExceptionManager.HandleException(ex);
    }
});
```

Inside CommunicateToservice method we will be calling the service and pass the request and get the response object and save to MS SQL DB around 10 -15 tables. The whole method is wrapped with AggregateException.

Need inputs on How the MaxDegreeOfParallelism value can be decided.

Comment: If this is really processing a batch of similar items, you may want to communicate that batch to the service once and have the service handle the multi-threading. Maybe even using batch handling for sql so it is in one single process but still faster than threaded. Threading, especially if every thread is doing heavy lifting, is not neccessarily faster than good batch processing.

Comment: Communicatetoservice method does calling external service for response and upon arrival saves it to DB. I mean method handles multi-threading

Comment: Maybe it's faster to send all requests in one batch, have them handled and save them to the database in one batch. There are very efficient batch-handling APIs for most databases and you don't have the overhead of multiple service calls. But only you can know if that would be faster or not.

Answer (score 3):

For IO-bound work there is no easy guideline. You don't know what the point of optimal throughput is. Test different values and measure which one is the fastest.

You probably should not set the DOP too high because that might overload the remote service.

Comment: Overloading the remote service is something that's happening in our app. How can we prevent that? We're looking for a way to be more conservative in scaling up the simultaneous calls and that scales down when a call times out. Any suggestions for this?

Comment: @spike you should probably ask this as a new question. Sounds like a great one!

Comment: done: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22656669/prevent-overload-on-remote-system-when-using-parallel-foreach