# Prevent overload on remote system when using Parallel.ForEach()

Tags: c#, multithreading, parallel-processing, task-parallel-library, parallel.foreach

We've built this app that needs to have some calculations done on a remote machine (actually a MatLab server). We're using web services to connect to the MatLab server and perform the calculations.

In order to speed things up, we've used `Parallel.ForEach()` in order to have multiple service calls going at the same time. If we're very conservative in setting `ParallelOptions.MaxDegreeOfParallelism` (DOP) to 4 or something, everything works fine and well.
However, if we let the framework decide on the DOP it will spawn so many threads that it forces the remote machine on its knees and timeouts start occurring ( > 10 minutes ).

How can we solve this issue? What I would LOVE to be able to do is use the response time to throttle the calls. If response time is less than 30 sec, keep adding threads, as soon as it's over 30 sec, use less. Any suggestions?

N.B. Related to the response in this question: [Parallel Foreach webservice call](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20192692/896697).

Comment: Related: [Is it possible to change parallelOptions.MaxDegreeOfParallelism during execution of a Parallel.ForEach?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3705006/is-it-possible-to-change-paralleloptions-maxdegreeofparallelism-during-execution)

Answer (score 2):

Simplest way would be to tune for the best number of concurrent requests and hardcode that as you have done so far, however there are some nicer options if you are willing to put in some effort.

You could move from a Parallel.ForEach to [using a thread pool](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3dasc8as.aspx). That way as things come back from the remote server you can either manually or programatically tune the number of available threads. reducing/increasing the number of available threads as things slow down/speed up, or even kill them if needed.

You could also do a variant of the above [using Tasks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd537609%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) which are the newer way of doing parallel/async stuff in .net.

Another option would be to use a timers and/or jobs model to schedule jobs every x milliseconds, which could then be throttled/relaxed as results returned from the server. The easiest way to get started would be [using Quartz.Net](http://www.quartz-scheduler.net/).